# Emulator stopped working

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I'm very new to the android programming

I'm trying to execute the app which I was writing from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html),

but I can't able to run the app. When I'm trying to run the app, the emulator shows

> the Abc(app name) suddenly stopped working

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.xyz.abc;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.xyz.Abc.MESSAGE";


/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

DisplayMessageActivity.java

```
 package com.xyz.abc;

 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.os.Build;

 public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() { }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
              Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_message,
                  container, false);
          return rootView;
    }
}
}
```

fragment_display_message.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.xyz.abc.DisplayMessageActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/edit_message" />

</LinearLayout>
```

below is the logcat output for error.

> 05-07 06:11:21.004: D/AndroidRuntime(1143): Shutting down VM
>       05-07 06:11:21.004: W/dalvikvm(1143): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2aabba8)
>       05-07 06:11:21.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1143): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       05-07 06:11:21.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1143): Process: com.xyz.abc, PID: 1143
>       05-07 06:11:21.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1143): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.xyz.abc/com.xyz.abc.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat
>   theme (or descendant) with this activity.
>       05-07 06:11:21.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
>       05-07 06:11:21.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>       05-07 06:11:21.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>       05-07 06:11:21.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>       05-07 06:11:21.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>       05-07 06:11:21.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>       05-07 06:11:21.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>       05-07 06:11:21.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       05-07 06:11:21.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>       05-07 06:11:21.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>       05-07 06:11:21.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>       05-07 06:11:21.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>       05-07 06:11:21.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1143): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat
>   theme (or descendant) with this activity.
>       05-07 06:11:21.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):   at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:108)
>       05-07 06:11:21.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):   at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:57)
>       05-07 06:11:21.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):   at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
>       05-07 06:11:21.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):   at com.xyz.abc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
>       05-07 06:11:21.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>       05-07 06:11:21.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>       05-07 06:11:21.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
>       05-07 06:11:21.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):   ... 11 more
>       05-07 06:11:29.494: I/Process(1143): Sending signal. PID: 1143 SIG: 9

Comment: use the button and edittext initializations in oncreate() activity,may be that is issue.

Comment: can you post your logcat

Comment: Post your activity_main.xml

Comment: @mussharapp  i already posted the activity_main.xml

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

This is the reason that your app crashes. Look at your manifest, find the theme of your activity or application and ensure that it extends some AppCompat theme, for ex. the auto-generated project in newest Android Studio has it like so:
**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
       ...
 android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

**styles.xml**

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
       ...
 </style>
```